# Get SVN commit revision number in Python 3, "Client.info" from pysvn does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysvn

This code worked for me in Python 2.7:

```
client = pysvn.Client()
entry = client.info(file_path)
commit_revision = entry.data.get('commit_revision').number
```

But in Python 3.8 after installing pysvn 0.1.0 using pip I get the error

> 'Client' object has no attribute 'info'

What can I use for commit revision in Python 3.8?

Comment: Which version of pysvn are you using (output of `print(pysvn.version)`), and how did you install it?

Comment: Are you specifically asking how to do this using the pysvn library, or would any interface to SVN work?

Comment: version 0.1.0, pip install. what are the differences between pysvn and svn?

Comment: SVN is a version control system and pysvn is a library to use it from Python.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you were using the library PySVN from [here](https://pysvn.sourceforge.io/) before, which according to the documentation does have a [`Client.info`](https://pysvn.sourceforge.io/Docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_info) method returning an `Entry` object.

But by using `pip install pysvn`, you got [pysvn](https://pypi.org/project/pysvn/), which is a different library, although it has a similar name.

If you want to use the library you were used to, uninstall the one from pip again and follow the installation instructions on https://pysvn.sourceforge.io/downloads.html instead.